# How to disable EditText copy/paste?

Tags: android

I searched a lot of possibilities but does not get a solution I tried the below codes. please give the solution. I am trying to create a payment related application in the Edit text account number will be entered by the user that way I'm asking this solution thanks.

```
editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    });

editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return false;
        }
    });

editText.setLongClickable(false);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add longClickable in your xml file

```
<EditText
    ... your edittext
   android:longClickable = "false"/>
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working and I also mentioned your solution in java but it same as XML